# How to show URL icon with text in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have tried different ways to show a URL icon with text but didnt succeed. Here is the code and its output snippets

**Example 1:**

```
let text = "I am text"
let myWebsite = URL(string:"https://www.youtube.com/")
let shareAll = [text, myWebsite] as [Any]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareAll, applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Output 1:**
[UIActivity View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSDl6.png) [Messages View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t21nh.png)

**Example 2:**

```
let myWebsite = URL(string:"https://www.youtube.com/")
let shareAll = [myWebsite] as [Any]
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareAll, applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Output 2:**

[UIActivity View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5b2c.png)

**Required:**
I want URL icon like in Output 2 for Example 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between *sharing* data and *showing* data - I think in your case, showing the data that's about to be shared.

I could be wrong, but if not, you are *actually* able to share the data - in this case a `UIImage` and text - but wish to display what is *about* to be shared. I had this issue a while back. Here's my code. See if it can help you - basically you need to add metadata to `UIActivityViewController` delegate.

```
func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
    let shareImage = preview.uiImage.adjustedForShareSheetPreviewIconProvider()
    let imageProvider = NSItemProvider(object: shareImage)
    let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
    metadata.imageProvider = imageProvider
    metadata.title = "Title"
    return metadata
}
```

Adjust `shareImage` and `title` as needed.

**EDIT**

I was using my code and was incomplete. `adjustedForShareSheetPreviewIconProvider()` is part of `UIImage`, and as such, it assumes this. In my code, I'm actually calling a `GLKView` to return this `UIImage` and then use it this way in the metadata.

So if your image is something returned from the URL as an icon **and** is (or can be converted to) a `UIImage`, just add it to the metadata like my code above.

Comment: preview.uiImage.adjustedForShareSheetPreviewIconProvider() does this function call return an UIImage object?

Comment: No. I will update my answer.